# can we call the master file from "login.aspx" fileResponse.Redirect("Site.Master");

Tags: asp.net

can we master file from "login.aspx"  file it gives me error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

Comment: A master is a template container that gets merged to the page implementing it, when a request for the page comes. A master does not exist as a self-standing page, so you simply cannot redirect to it.

Comment: thnx alot mr Sain Pradeep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, You can't. However you can create empty `aspx` page with a master as `Site.master` and call that page.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the Default.aspx
or use FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username, False)